# Is project uploaded on git visible publicly?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git. I just wanted to know whenever we use git for code sharing, is that code visible to everyone who searches on git? What if I don't want to show it to public and use it internally. Is this possible. I don't even want it to appear as read only. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Do you mean github when you mention git in your post? `git !== github`

Comment: And if you mean github- they have private repositories as an option.

Comment: ..."searches on git" isn't even a thing. There is no "git" search interface, except within a given repository as with `git grep`. If the question is about GitLab or GitHub or SourceForge or CodeBase or Launchpad or BitBucket or Beanstalk or Assembla or any of the other hundreds of hosting services... well, it's better addressed by looking at that individual hosting service's documentation. And of course, you can use git with only your own private servers, not uploading your repository to any system owned by anyone else at all.

Answer (score 2):

So if you're using Github, when you push your code up it will be visible to everyone. However you can get yourself a paid account and have hidden repositories. If you are looking for a free alternative, where you can have private repositories then you could use BitBucket.

Comment: If this were a direct answer, the question would be off-topic (violating the rules against product or service recommendation requests).

Answer (score 1):

... or you could just stick to keeping your own git repos on your own servers.

Answer (score 1):

Boss, most of the git hosting sites like GitHub, bitbucket etc, provides you with a paid service to keep your code hidden from the whole world, they can't able to search, not even they can see your code. This feature is called Private repository. 
If you are having the private repo, then your code is secured and purely private to you. But on the other hand, they also provide free service known as public repo by default. All the code in public repo is visible to every individual.